# Add contact using popup

Tags: visualforce

I have a page block table with 2 columns
1st - Application Name and 2nd - Add Contact button

Clicking of Add button opens up a popup to add contact
There are 3 fields in pop

First Name, Last Name and Email
2 button Add and Cancel on popup.

Assign -- Adds contact to application (Contact has application as lookup field on it)
Cancel -- Just simply closes the popup

Not sure how do i add contact to application?

Following is the code i m trying

```
public with sharing class TestAddContact {

    public boolean displayPopup {get; set;}

    public List<Id,Application__c> lstApplication{get;set;}

    public TestAddContact(){
        lstApplication = [SELECT Id, Name
                          FROM Application__c 
                          WHERE         Client__c = : account.Id 
                          ORDER BY  CreatedDate Desc]);
    } 

    public void closePopup(){        
        displayPopup = false;    
    } 

    public void showPopup(){        
        displayPopup = true;
        applicationId = applicationId;
        if(applicationId != null){  

        }     
    } 
}
```

Visualforce page code

```
<apex:page><style type="text/css">
    .custPopup{
        background-color: white;
        border-width: 2px;
        border-style: solid;
        z-index: 9999;
        left: 50%;
        padding:10px;
        position: absolute;
        width: 500px;
        margin-left: -250px;
        top:100px;
    }
    .popupBackground{
        background-color:black;
        opacity: 0.20;
        filter: alpha(opacity = 20);
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 9998;
    }</style>

<apex:pageBlock>
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!lstApplication}" var="application">
    <apex:column headerValue="Application Name">
        <apex:outputText value="{!application.Name}"  style="font-size:10px;font-weight:bold"/>
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column headerValue ="Action">
        <apex:commandButton value="delegate" rerender="opDelegateContact" action="{!showPopup}" >
            <apex:param name="applicationId" value="{!application.Id}" assignTo="{!applicationId}" />
        </apex:commandButton>
    </apex:column>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>

<apex:outputPanel id="opContact">
    <apex:outputPanel styleClass="popupBackground" layout="block" rendered="{!displayPopUp}"/>
<apex:outputPanel styleClass="custPopup" layout="block" rendered="{!displayPopUp}">
<apex:pageBlock id="pbContact" >
<table><tr> <td>
<apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
<apex:outputText value="First Name" />
<apex:inputText value="{!contact.FirstName}"/>
<br/>
<apex:outputText value="Last Name" />
<apex:inputText value="{!contact.LastName}"/><br/>
<apex:outputText value="Email" /><apex:inputText value="{!contact.Email}"/>
<br/></apex:pageBlockSection></td></tr><tr><td>
<apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!closePopup}" rerender="opContact"/>
<apex:commandButton value="Add" rerender="opContact" action="{!showPopup}" >
<apex:param name="applicationId" value="{!application.Id}" assignTo="{!applicationId}" />
</apex:commandButton>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

First i would use `apex:actionFunction` to open a Contact window and at the same time pass the current application ID in controller (we will need this ID for a new Contact object):

```
<apex:actionFunction name="open" action="{!showPopup}" reRender="Contract">
    <apex:param name="p1" assignTo="{!currentApplication}" value="">
</apex:actionFunction>

<apex:pageBlock id="Table">
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!applications}" var="application">
        <apex:column value="{!application.name}"/>
        <apex:column headerValue ="Action">
            <apex:commandButton value="Open popup" onclick="open('{!application.id}');"/> 
        </apex:column>
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>

<apex:outputPanel id="Contract">
    <apex:inputField value="{!con.FirstName}"/>
    <apex:inputField value="{!con.astName}"/>
    <apex:inputField value="{!con.Email}"/>
    <apex:commandButton value="Add" reRender="Table, Contract" action="{!addContact}" >
</apex:outputPanel>
```

In controller just paas the current application ID into the lookup field and save a new contact. At te same time we need to rerender two panels "Table" and "Contract" to refresh a new data:

```
public Contact con { get; set; }
public String currentApplication { get; set; }

public YourClass(){
    con = new Contact();
    currentApplication = '';
}

public PageReference addContact(){
    // Inserting new contact
    con.application__c = currentApplication;
    insert con;

    // Initialising a new contact object
    con = new Contact();    

    return null;
}
```